# Receiving grunt error when installing/setting up project with mean.io

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, mean-stack

I have installed mean.io through npm. I have updated node, grunt, bower and have used mean init to create my project.

I then cd into the project directory and "sudo npm install".

I now try running grunt and receive an error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'meanio'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
```

Can someone explain why this is happening? Have I installed mean.io incorrectly?

Comment: Did you install mean.io globally or locally?

Answer (score 0):

You should not run thr npm install as root.
All of the installtion is as a normal user excluding the

`sudo initial npm install -g mean-cli`

If you still have problems chown all you directory to -

`chown -R youUser *`

You might still have permissions as root at ~/.npm - so examine that and chown there as well.